# Bounded linear operator on Banach space $C[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Question : Let $C[0,1]$ be the Banach space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with supremum norm . Discussed about boundedness of the operator $T$ on $C[0,1]$ and it’s inverse, where $T$ is given by $T(f)(x)=\int_0^x xf(t)dt$.

I tried as below

$$\|T(f)\|=sup |\int_0^x xf(t)dt|\leq sup\int_0^x |xf(t)|dt\leq \|f\|sup|x|=\|f\|$$

So $\|T(f)\|\leq \|f\|$, which implies that $T$ is bounded with norm $1$. One more thing I noted that $T$ is one one so invertible, but I am unable to tell about boundedness of $T^{-1}$ on range $R$ of $T$. Please help me to tell about boundedness of $T^{-1}$ on $R$, and tell me the way I checked bounded of $T$ is correct? Thank you .

Comment: Technically you only showed it is bounded and its norm is no more than 1, not that it is 1

Comment: @Alan thank you ....please can you write about  boundedness of inverse of T ?

Comment: Sorry, been too long since my functional analysis days.  I've actually just started to review my textbook for fun

Comment: T is the composition of the Volterra operator and a multiplication operator. Volterra operator is not surjective! Its image is $C^1[0,1]$. And $C^1[0,1]$ is invariant under the multiplication operator. So T is not surjective, hence it is not invertible.

Comment: @TimurBakiev sir about invertible on its range ?? I am editing it ..

Comment: @TimurBakiev I edit the question ... $T$ is one one and onto from $[0,1]$ to its range ... please now comment ... thank you .

Comment: @TimurBakiev can I say something like     If $T^{-1}$ is also continuous then space of continuous functions is homeomorphic to space of continuously differentiable functions on $ [0,1]$ ? Related to this ?

Comment: @neelkanth Multiplication by x is not invertible too, so there are a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proved that $T$ is bounded with $\|T\| \leq 1$.

Let $f_n(x)=nx$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac 1 n$ and $f_n(x)=n(\frac  2 n -x)$ for $\frac 1 n \leq x \leq \frac 2 n$. Then $f_n$ is continuous and $\|f_n\|=1$ for each $n$. You can easily check that $\|Tf_n|| \leq \frac 2 n$. So there cannot be any positive constant $c$ such that $\|Tf \| \geq c \|f\|$ for all $f$. It follows that $T$ does not have a continuous inverse.

Comment: thank you very much sir ...

Comment: sir I think $f(x)=x^n$ also working in place of $f_n$ given by you ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.